# Remote Desktop - Font Size

Tags: virtual-machines, remote-desktop, font

I hope this is a right group for posting this question.  I have Azure VM- Win 2008-R2. When I remote to the Font size is too small. Unfortunately the option to change this has been grayed out and I can't change the size.

Is there a way of changing the font size?

Regards
Ardy

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the following command?

'mstsc.exe /w:1024 /h:768'  (change values to your preferred size.)

Using /w and /h simply set the width and height of the mstsc window.  It does nothing about the DPI within the window.  Fonts are still small and very hard to read in that window.  See the mstsc command line reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907(WS.10).aspx

I hope this information be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... is this in command screen (i.e old dos) window... cmd.exe?

Comment: "DOS" is ancient history to modern Windows NT. You can assume commands and their arguments are for use in shortcuts, or PowerShell scripts.

Comment: Thank you your reply. I will try this with the power shell.